# Add years to existing field in MongoDb (prior 4.2 version)

Tags: mongodb

Please, can someone tell me how to add 100 yrs to existing "created_at" field in aggregation.
MongoDb version is 3.4.14

smtng like:

```
db.coll.aggregate([
        { $project: { 
        consent_end_date: { **$addyears**: [ $created_at, 100] }}
    ])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sample use `$add` operator.
Please check link below https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/#examples

You query will be something like this

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    { 
        $project: { 
            consentEndDate: { $add: [ "$createdAt", 100] }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Tnx, but it not completely correct, I need to add 100 yrs, accordint to that it will looks like:
`db.sales.aggregate(
   [
     { $project: { consentEndDate: { $add: [ "$createdAt", 100*365*24*60*60000 ] } } }
   ]
)`
But that not taking cares about lap years , because its just adding days to current $createdAt field, but not every year is 365 days long (lap years).